# How to wait for one function to execute before executing second function in microsoft bot framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I am calling a function which processes the user input message and then sends a response accordingly in microsoft bot framework's node.js SDK. Here is the scenario: When the bot receives the message from user, I am calling a function `processMessage` which takes some time to execute. `processedResult` is the result which is obtained after `processMessage` is executed. Since the bot is responding prematurely, it is sending an undefined value. How to ensure the next step in the waterfall isn't executed before the execution of `processMessage` is complete?  Here is my code:

```
var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {
        console.log('step1')
        processMessage(session.message.text);
    },
    function(session) {
        console.log('step3')
        session.send(processedResult);
    }
]);
```

`console.log('step2')` is in the definition of `processMessage`. The order of logs is step1, step3, step2.

Comment: Does `processMessage` take a callback?

Comment: No. But if a callback helps, I will add it.  Please explain the solution using a callback, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Your `processMessage` function needs to return a Promise. The, you can just do a `.then` there to do the log of the step3.

Something like the following (I wrote the code here, so it might contains minor errors)

```
function processMessage(text) {
 return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(text);
    var processedResult = 'myProcessedResult';
    resolve(processedResult);
 }
}

bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {
        console.log('step1')
        processMessage(session.message.text).then(processedResult) => {
         console.log('step3')
         session.send(processedResult);
    }
]);
```

Promises is a common pattern in the `Node.js`/`Javascript` world. You might want to read about them, for example [here](https://www.promisejs.org/).

In [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS) you could see how this approach being used: [the caller](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS/app.js#L63-L77) and the [function returning a Promise](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS/store.js#L12-L33).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with callback DP (You can either call next or prompt when returning from the callback):

```
var processMessage = (callback) => {
    request('...', (a, b, b) => {
       callback(null, 'ok');
    });
}

bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session, next) {
        console.log('step1')
        processMessage(session.message.text, (err, result) => {
            session.send(result);
            next();
        });
    },
    function(session, next) {
        console.log('step3')
        processMessage(session.message.text, (err, result) => {
            builder.Prompts.confirm(session, result);
        });
    }
]);
```